# Missing dependencies!

Tags: webbrowser-app

I installed Ubuntu on an old laptop and it seemed just fine, then I installed 'chrome' browser and I now have a red symbol top right of screen which tells me that I have software that is missing some dependencies. Which means absolutely nothing to me!

I tried to remove the chrome software but it won't go away. What should I do?
I have no knowledge of developing or programming - I'm just an Ubuntu OS user!

Comment: For the chrome browser no need to remove it. What version of lInux are you using?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This is an image of my `desktop` a bit different from yours because the bar (`unity launcher`) you see at the bottom of the screen would be found to your left in yours.

At the extreme left side of mine and top of yours you can see the Ubuntu icon. That is called the `dash` from here you can search and launch items.

Now follow these steps:

1. click the `dash` icon and a semi-transparent window or box will appear.
2. type in `software updater`
3. when it searches and brings up the icon for these tool, `click` on it.

It will search your installed software repositories and update it if it needs to be.

The icon you spoke of should disappear, but if it doesn't please `reboot` or `restart` your system.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it has made no difference. I still can't remove the chrome icon from the apps folder and it seems to be preventing me from doing anything much. I can still use firefox but can't add any more software. I am using ubuntu 16.04lts and the danger icon comes on without touching anything.

Comment: what do you mean by apps folder? The answer was not meant to remove the chrome icon rather update it as you had said you were unable to do so, is the error icon at the top right still there and what is it preventing from doing?

Comment: what I meant was that I tried to uninstall chrome earlier as this problem only occurred after installation, but I can't! and  I tried to install some other software but I can't do that either.

Comment: When I tried the software updater it just flashed for a while in the unity launcher then disappeared!

Comment: Please what version of Ubuntu are you using and how did you install chrome from the `command line or Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu16.04lts and I installed chrome from a downloaded package. It seems to have come with a problem because now the updater does not work. I'm sure half the problem is because I do not really know what I'm doing!!